# C# Unzip a textfile (.GetInputStream()) from an archive to string using SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sharpziplib

How do you unzip a textfile from a zip archive to string?

Does the textfile also need `MemoryStream` or `StreamReader` like the image binary?

Specifically:

```
        foreach (ZipEntry e in zipFile)
        {
            if (e.IsFile)
            {
                string ext = Path.GetExtension(e.Name).ToLower();
                print(ext + " " + e.Name);
                if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".tga")
                {
                    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1);
                    Stream zipStream = zipFile.GetInputStream(e);
                    tex.LoadImage(ReadFully(zipStream));

                    dicTexture.Add(e.Name,tex );
                } else if (ext == ".txt")
                {
                    Stream zipStream = zipFile.GetInputStream(e);
                    dicTxt.Add(e.Name, Encoding.Default.GetString(zipStream.)); // how do you populate this string here? 
                }
            }
        }


public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As with any stream, you can use a StreamReader wrapped around the Stream and call [ReadToEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=netcore-3.1)

```
using(var x = new StreamReader(stream)){
  var theString =  x.ReadToEnd();
  //use theString
}
```

If you want to specify an encoding, the [constructor can take a second parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_) for that

Comment: When do you use `MemoryStream` vs `StreamReader` ? Also updated to show ReadFully()

Comment: Also after you have used the stream reader, how do you convert it to a string?

Comment: A MemoryStream is a Stream. A StreamReader is not a Stream, it's a reader (TextReader). It reads from a stream and produces strings. You do not convert a StreamReader to a string in the same way that you do not convert a shipyard to an oil tanker. You use a StreamReader to read from a stream and produce a string in the same way you use a shipyard to produce an oil tanker. I did that in my answer. Where I wrote `stream`, that's any stream - such as your `zipStream` obtained by calling `zipFile.GetInputStream(e)`.

Comment: You can use a MemoryStream to adapt between a byte array and a stream, if you have a context that requires one and a context that requires the other. You don't need to use it in this case; you could just ask the zip file how big the entry is, create an array that big and then read from the stream and write the array. MemoryStream in this sense is a bit wasteful of resources particularly because ToArray is a copy operation, but ultimately it works as you want and should be left alone until you better understand the internal workings